# Logical OR in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, logical-operators

Here is where I want to implement my `OR`

```
return bigData.country==["US"||"JP"] && (bigData.description=="iPhone 4S")
```

> [ A `||` B `||` C `||` ... ]  `&&` [ X `||` Y `||` Z `||`....]

As you can see above, I am returning objects, if the value of key of object `bigData.country` is either `US` or `JP`, `AND` `bigData.description` is either `iPhone 4S`, can also be more devices.

I'm able to get the desired result, by

```
return (bigData.country=="US"||bigData.country=="JP") && (bigData.description=="iPhone 4S")
```

But as I can have convenience to add and remove from an Array, I am trying to use an array. Suggestion to use something different is also welcomed.

If you want to play around with my code here is **[REPL](https://repl.it/@dhavaljardosh1/Big-Data)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.indexOf` (to be `!= -1`) like this:

```
return ["US", "JP"].indexOf(bigData.country) !== -1 && ["X", "Y", "Z"].indexOf(bigData.description) !== -1;
```

Or in ES6, you can use `Array.prototype.includes` like:

```
return ["US", "JP"].includes(bigData.country) && ["X", "Y", "Z"].includes(bigData.description);
```

Answer (score 2):

With an Array:

```
return ['US','JP'].indexOf(bigData.country) >= 0 &&
       ['iPhone 4S'].indexOf(bigData.description) >= 0;
```

With an object (possibly better performance):

```
return {'US': true,'JP': true}[bigData.country] &&
       {'iPhone 4S': true}[bigData.description];
```

---

As pointed out by [@ibrahim mahrir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6647153/ibrahim-mahrir), the object approach doesn't always work. For example, if `bigData.country=='toString'`. This is because Javascript objects come with a default baggage of methods from their default `Object` prototype. In a real world scenario the likelihood of running afoul of this problem is negligible, but if you want to do it really really properly, there are two options:

1 - Use `hasOwnProperty()`:

```
return {'US': true,'JP': true}.hasOwnProperty(bigData.country) &&
       {'iPhone 4S': true}.hasOwnProperty(bigData.description);
```

2 - Use an object WITHOUT a prototype. This is more verbose to set up, but also more convenient to use. You can also write a trivial method that converts a regular object to a prototype-less object.

```
var countries = new Object(null);
countries['US'] = true;
countries['JP'] = true;

var descriptions = new Object(null);
descriptions['iPhone 4S'] = true;

return countries[bigData.country] &&
       descriptions[bigData.description];
```

Comment: The second method is not very reliable. If `bigData.description === "toString"` for example... Maybe use `hasOwnProperty`, but then we're back at the first one again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`Array#some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** like this:

**ES6:**

```
return ['US','JP'].some(val => bigData.country === val) && ['iPhone 4S'].some(v => bigData.description === v);
```

**ES5:**

```
return ['US','JP'].some(function(val){return bigData.country === val}) && ['iPhone 4S'].some(function(v){return bigData.description === v});
```

---

**Demo:**

```js
let bigData = {
  country: 'JP',
  description: 'iPhone 4S'
};

console.log(['US', 'JP'].some(val => bigData.country === val) && ['iPhone 4S'].some(v => bigData.description === v));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an ES6 [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) ([REPL](https://repl.it/repls/WateryAvariciousSwallowtail)):

```js
const countriesToKeep = new Set(['GP', 'US']);

console.log(countriesToKeep.has('UK'));

console.log(countriesToKeep.has('GP'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.prototype.includes` is most likely what you're after:

```js
let valid = {
  countries: ['US', 'JP'],
  description: 'iPhone 4S'
};
let dataset = [{
  country: 'US',
  description: 'iPhone 4S',
  expected: true
}, {
  country: 'JP',
  description: 'iPhone 4S',
  expected: true
}, {
  country: 'AA',
  description: 'iPhone 4S',
  expected: false
}, {
  country: 'US',
  description: 'iPhone',
  expected: false
}]

// iterate over data values
dataset.forEach(data => {
  let is_valid = valid.countries.includes(data.country) && valid.description == data.description;
  
  console.log(
    `Country:"${data.country}"`,
    `Description:"${data.description}"`,
    `Expected:${data.expected}`,
    `Got:${is_valid}`
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object as data structure for testing:

```
var countries = {
        US: true,
        JP: true
    };


return countries[bigData.country] && ...
```